# Getting JSON input and pass it into a function in PHP

Tags: php, json, class, object

I've got 4 classes responsive for:
1st - getting input as JSON string from url, decode it into an array and create 2 `variables: $user_id, $user_text (like here below):`

```
class Get_message{
    public $user_id, $user_text;

    public function get_input(){

        $input = json_decode(file_get_contents('myURL'), true);
        $user_id = $input['getting value from an array'];
        $user_text = $input['getting value from an array'];

        //how to return it?
        //return $input, $user_id, $user_text? it won't work I guess
    }
}
```

and there is my first question: how to return that 2 values so that I can use it in another classes?

2nd - check if that string contains keywords, if it contains a keyword I want to create another JSON,
so far I've got this:

```
class input_recognize{
const KEYWORD_HELP = 'help';
//...some more constants...
const KEYWORD_REPORT = 'report';

public function msg_recognize($user_text)
{
    switch ($user_text) {
        case self::KEYWORD_HELP:
            return new Output_msg(Output_msg::MESS_HELP);
        break;
        //... some more cases
        case self::KEYWORD_REPORT:
            return new Output_message(Output_msg::MESS_REPORT);
        break;
    }
}
```

}

3rd - based on that what case in class above was true create appropriate JSON, my code looks like:

```
class Output_message{

    const MESS_REPORT = 1;
    const MESS_HELP = 2;

    public function __construct($user_id, $user_text){
         //I guess I should use $this here, dunno how

        $json_output = array(
            "first_title" => array(
                "id" => $user_id
            ),
            "second_title" => array(
                "text" => "text to send"
            ),
        );
        $output = json_encode($json_ouput);
    }
}
```

4th - and I want to be able to take $output into that function and POST it to url.

I'm beginner in php, object oriented programming as well, I'll appreciate any help, and criticism. Thanks in advice.

Comment: Don't use constant in your case statements.

Comment: instead of `KEYWORD_HELP` use just `'help'`?

Comment: Yes, because it will produce the same result and i think it's the best way for static values.

Comment: thank you for answer. could you say anything about one of these questions?

Comment: how are you using MESS_REPORT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can use the same class to do everything you have done, using methods. For those input variables declare them as public static and use your class constructor to set them. `public static $userId;    self::$userId =` .... and cal `GetMesage::userId`.
2. Use `strpos('help', $yourString)`, no need for constants here.
3. I don't think you need to do that in a class constructor, if you do you can add more methods. Like you set you values in constructor new `OutputMessage(GetMessage::$userId, GetMessage::$userText);`
4. use a method like sendOutput()  and post your data to url using curl.

I do not advice you to do it like you did, you can use only a class, and pass data form a method to another, you won't really need output or input, only the 2 url's. If you really want 4 classes then you can chain them, one class will return another.

This is just demonstrative, there are a loot of ways of achieving what you want, this is an example:

```
class Message{
    public static $userId;
    public static $userText;
    public static $messageType;

    public function __construct($inputUrl)
    {
        $this->getMessage($inputUrl);
        $this->parseMessage();
    }

    private function getMessage($inputUrl){

        $input = json_decode(file_get_contents($inputUrl), true);
        self::$userId = $input['id'];
        self::$userText = $input['text'];
    }

    private function parseMessage()
    {
        $messageText = self::$userText;
        switch (true) {
            case (strpos('help',$messageText) !== false):
                self::$messageType = "Help"; //or code, or whatever you want here
                break;
            //... some more cases
            case (strpos('report',$messageText) !== false):
                self::$messageType = "Report"; //or code, or whatever you want here
                break;
        }
    }

    public function sendResponse($outputUrl){

        $jsonOut = array(
            "first_title" => array(
                "id" => self::$userId
            ),
            "second_title" => array(
                "text" => "text to send"
            ),
        );
        $output = json_encode($jsonOut);

        $ch = curl_init($outputUrl);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $output);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                'Content-Type: application/json',
                'Content-Length: ' . strlen($output))
        );
        return curl_exec($ch);
    }
}

$sendMessage = new Message('inputUrl');
$sendMessage->sendResponse('outputUrl');
```

Comment: Thanks. How would you solve that, let me say, that app have to be 'stand-by' and waiting for message from user. When user sent message, then execute the code. How to deal with it?

Comment: You are getting the message and id from the URL, is that right? 1. if you do have a form somewhere on a html page, you make the form to target to a php file where you instantiate and call this class (but you would need something different). 2. if you have no idea when a user enters a text and this is an API call, you can make a method to check for messages at certain times. You change the class to fit your needs, add a method to check if the response is present (move part from the __construct()), and another to parse the message if it exists. You have no boundaries on how to do what you want.

Comment: It is facebook messenger api. When I used ordinary code (I mean that there weren't any classes, just `<?php //all code ?>`) it was working fine. Responding as fast as the message appeared.

Comment: Something was triggering the code, you can do the same here, and will work. you didn't change the functionality, you just arrange the code to me easier to read, use, change.

Comment: I've tried to init it by `__construct function`, unfortunately not working. How to debug that shit, I want to know what is responsible for that. `http://pastebin.com/yDBqEEFA`

Comment: instantiate the class in the file you are redirecting...where you had your previous code. $newmessage  = new Message();